# How to merge excel cells based on the cell value using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I am using excel interop with C#. I want to merge all adjacent cells that contain a specific value using C# code.

How to merge all the cells that contain the value (Merged cells) using C# code 
[![image 1][1]][1]

But I want something like this below,

[![image 2][2]][2]

Here is my full code, but it shows COM Exception handling

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using OfficeOpenXml;


namespace ExportExcel
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataTable ctr_raw_table = new DataTable();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ctr_raw_table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
        ctr_raw_table.Columns.Add("Company", typeof(String));
        ctr_raw_table.Columns.Add("Job", typeof(String));
        ctr_raw_table.Columns.Add("Level", typeof(String));
        ctr_raw_table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(String));
        ctr_raw_table.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(String));
        string[] row = new string[] { "John", "Wipro", "Engineer", "0203794", "India", "Mumbai" };
        ctr_raw_table.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "David", "TCS", "Engineer", "02065394", "India", "Thane" };
        ctr_raw_table.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "Albert", "Infosys", "Engineer", "0206394", "India", "Mumbai" };
        ctr_raw_table.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "Daniel", "IBM", "Engineer", "02036594", "India", "Mumbra" };
        ctr_raw_table.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "James", "Accenture", "Engineer", "02560394", "India", "Bhiwandi" };
        ctr_raw_table.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "Jacob", "L&T", "Engineer", "02036594", "India", "kalyan" };
        ctr_raw_table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Export_Ctr_Excel(ctr_raw_table, "Output");
    }
    private void Export_Ctr_Excel(DataTable tablelist, string excelFilename)
    {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objexcelapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        objexcelapp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        objexcelapp.Columns.AutoFit();
        for (int i = 1; i < tablelist.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objexcelapp.Cells[1, i];
            xlRange.Font.Bold = -1;
            //xlRange[objexcelapp.Cells["C2:C7"]].Merge();

            int Row = 1;
            int Column = 1;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range rng = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objexcelapp.Cells[Row, Column];
            rng.EntireColumn.Font.Bold = true;
            rng.EntireColumn.Font.Italic = true;
            //rng.EntireColumn.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.HotPink);
            rng.EntireColumn.BorderAround();

            xlRange.Borders.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;

            xlRange.VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

            //String startRange = "C1";
            //String endRange = "C7";
            //String repetitiveValue = "Merged Cells";
            //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlrange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objexcelapp.Cells[startRange, endRange];
            //xlrange.Value2 = repetitiveValue;
            //xlRange.Select();
            //xlrange.Merge(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

            objexcelapp.Cells[1, i] = tablelist.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;

            using (var excel = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo(@"physical_address_of_your_xslx_file")))
            {
                var sheetName = "Sheet1";
                var sheet1 = excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Output"];
                // or :
                //var sheet1 = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

                sheet1.Cells["C2:C7"].Merge = true;
                sheet1.Cells["C2:C7"].Style.VerticalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelVerticalAlignment.Bottom;
                sheet1.Cells["C2"].Value = "The value";

                excel.Save();
            }



            //DataTable dt = tablelist.Columns[i];
            //if (DataColumnCollection.tablelist.Column.Company = "Wipro")

            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow));
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red));
            //}

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tablelist.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tablelist.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (tablelist.Rows[i][j] != null)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objexcelapp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1];

                    xlRange.Borders.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;

                    xlRange.Borders.Weight = 1d;
                    xlRange.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                    objexcelapp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = tablelist.Rows[i][j].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        objexcelapp.Columns.AutoFit();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        if (Directory.Exists("C:\\CTR_Data\\"))
        {
            objexcelapp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs("C:\\CTR_Data\\" + excelFilename + ".xlsx");
        }
        else
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\CTR_Data\\");
            objexcelapp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs("C:\\CTR_Data\\" + excelFilename + ".xlsx");
        }
        objexcelapp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        foreach (Process proc in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL"))
        {
            proc.Kill();
        }
    }

    private object Worksheets(string v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Excel Interop uses the same calls used by VBA macros. You can record a macro while merging cells, inspect the code and use the same calles in your C# code.

Comment: `it shows COM Exception handling` what is the *actual* error? Post the full exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`, not just the message. The full text contains any inner exceptions and the full call stack that shows where the error occured.

Comment: (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))

Comment: That's not what `Exception.ToString()` would return.

Comment: Sir can you please review my coding where i am wrong...you must see attachments what i want...Thank you in advance sir

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack-overflow, I don't recommend to use `OfficeInterLopos` since they are not easy to use. They are dependent on Office dlls and etc.

There is a cool library calls `EPPLUS`. [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) is a .NET library that reads and writes Excel files using the Office Open XML format (xlsx). EPPlus **has no dependencies other than .NET**.  You can install it via [NUGET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus).

```
        using (var excel = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo(@"physical_address_of_your_xslx_file")))
        {
            var sheetName = "Sheet1";
            var sheet1 = excel.Workbook.Worksheets[sheetName];
            // or :
            // var sheet1 = excel.Workbook.Workseets.First();

            sheet1.Cells["C2:C7"].Merge = true;
            sheet1.Cells["C2:C7"].Style.VerticalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelVerticalAlignment.Bottom;
            sheet1.Cells["C2"].Value = "The value";

            excel.Save();                
        }
```

Not only it's easy to use but also very powerful and well-documented.

[image: Output example]

p.s: Don't forget to reference `using OfficeOpenXml;` on your code.

Comment: Its showing exceptional error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ExportExcel.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: In this line:                                                                                                                
 var sheet1 = excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

Comment: @AamirAhmad what's the name of your first sheet? you got to change `Sheet1` to the name of your changes. You can even use `First()` of `Linq` method.

Comment: @AamirAhmad I updated the code. If my solution worked for you, please don't forget to mark it as an accepted.

Comment: Sir can i share with you my full coding..because it's still showing same 'System.NullReferenceException' and i am junier in coding field but i want to learn more

Comment: @AamirAhmad update your question and put your code there.

Comment: When i'll debugg i found NULL exception. It's says Sheet1 value is NULL, this line: sheet1.Cells["C2:C7"].Merge = true;